# javascript - how to get the date after 1 year with MM-DD mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am creating a function to get the date.

The ultimate date I want to get is the date which is 1 year after.

The format is YYYY-MM-DD like `2022-03-31`.

YYYY must be 1 year after.(if today is 2021, YYYY = 2022)

The MM-DD must match:

```
03-31
06-30
09-30
12-31
```

The generated date must be at least 1 year after

For example, today is `2021-08-04`, the function should return `2022-09-30`.

I tried to study `moment.js`, but it does not give me idea of how to do it as it is used for formatting.

Comment: I might miss something, but `2022-09-30` is _not_ one year after `2021-08-04`. How do these relate?

Comment: @Evert I update detailed logic above. please check

Comment: I can give you last date of month after next year like, Right now i get result 2022-08-31 is this want you ?

Comment: if simple you want to add one year in today date then it will return 2022-08-04

Comment: @Wajid I am doing some seasonal calculation based on the date, so it must match the `MM-DD` rule I mention above

Comment: mean is its three months gap right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for plus 1 year, moved out to the next quarter-end.

Given any date in variable `someDate`:

```
function endOfQuarterNextYear(someDate) {
  // Create a copy since date will get changed
  var d = new Date(someDate);
  
  // Set the date out by 15 months
  // (1 year plus 1 quarter)
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 15);

  // Move back to start of quarter
  // % 3 means remainder after divide by 3, (and
  // note please that month numbers are 0-based in JS)
  // in month 9  (Oct) you will get month 9 (Oct)
  // in month 10 (Nov) you will get month 9 (Oct)
  // in month 11 (Dec) you will get month 9 (Oct)
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - (d.getMonth() % 3));

  // Move back to last day of prior month, which is
  // also last day in prior quarter
  // (and which is day '0' in current month)
  d.setDate(0);

  return d;
}

// To format the date, just take any date object
// and call:
someDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
// Gives 2021-09-30 type format

// So:
const someDate = new Date();
const nextYearQtr = endOfQuarterNextYear(someDate);
console.log(nextYearQtr.toISOString().slice(0,10));
// 2022-09-30 as of current date
```